# If the row underneath the previous row equals the first column's specific value, print the two rows

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a variable input file which could be formatted as below.

```
text1 valueA valueN valueB
text2 valueX
text1 valueC valueN valueD
text2 valueX
text1 valueE valueM valueF
text1 valueG valueM valueH
text1 valueI valueN valueJ
text2 valueX
text1 valueK valueO valueL
text1 valueP valueO valueQ
text1 valueR valueN valueS
text1 valueT valueM valueU
```

I only want to print `text1 valueA valueN valueB` if `text2 valueX` exists underneath the previous row. For example, the output should be:

```
text1 valueA valueN valueB
text2 valueX
text1 valueC valueN valueD
text2 valueX
text1 valueI valueN valueJ
text2 valueX
```

I also need to be able to match part of `valueX`. Let's say `valueX=a.b.c.d-e`, I need to match `a.b.`

```
myvariable=a.b.
echo $myvariable
a.b.
```

**Update**:
Apologies for the unclear input data... I asumed I could match partial text, but I was wrong.

So if the data looked like this:

```
text1 valueA valueN valueB
text2 a.b.c.d-e
text1 valueC valueN valueD
text2 a.b.c.d-e
text1 valueE valueM valueF
text1 valueG valueM valueH
text1 valueI valueN valueJ
text2 a.b.c.d-e
text1 valueK valueO valueL
text1 valueP valueO valueQ
text1 valueR valueN valueS
text1 valueT valueM valueU
```

How would you match, for example, `a.b.`, if `val=a.b.`

```
echo $val
a.b.
```

Comment: _to match part of `valueX`, for example: `val`_ Please, give an example (as `val` is part of every record).

Comment: That was dumb of me :D... so if `valueX` is `a.b.c.d-e`, how do you, for example, match it as `a.b.`?

Comment: If I `awk '$0~/text2 val/{print p ORS $0}{p=$0}' file` I get an output:
`text1 valueA valueN valueB
text2 valueX`
etc...

But if `val=val`

`awk '$0~/text2 $val/{print p ORS $0}{p=$0}' file` returns nothing

- @JamesBrown

Comment: That's  not how you use variables in awk, you need to introduce them with, for example `awk -v var=val 'BEGIN{print var}'` so in that case it would be `awk -v s=val '$0~"text2 " s {THE REST}`.

Comment: Thanks, everyone for the help. All posts are correct and it is extremely interesting seeing all the different methods!

Comment: @JamesBrown yes, thanks for the clarification on the awk variables. I have commented on your post using the awk var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one in awk:

```
$ awk '$0=="text2 valueX"{print p ORS $0}{p=$0}' file
```

Output:

```
text1 valueA valueN valueB
text2 valueX
text1 valueC valueN valueD
text2 valueX
text1 valueI valueN valueJ
text2 valueX
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
$0=="text2 valueX" {  # if record is a match
    print p ORS $0    # print previous buffered record and current
}
{
    p=$0              # buffer record for next round
}' file
```

**Updated update** with updated data:

As `.` is a regex metachar it needs to be escaped at input to avoid matching with, for example, `abbb`:

```
$ awk -v s="a\\\.b\\\." '$0~s{print p ORS $0}{p=$0}' file
```

Output now:

```
text1 valueA valueN valueB
text2 a.b.c.d-e
text1 valueC valueN valueD
text2 a.b.c.d-e
text1 valueI valueN valueJ
text2 a.b.c.d-e
```

Comment: Updated with partial match.

Comment: What I have done is replace the `.` with an `_` with `cat file | sed 's/\./_/g' > file2`.
I then set `var2=a_b_`.
Now `awk -v s="$var2" '$0~s{print p ORS $0}{p=$0}' file2` gives good output with underscores, but I can change that back to dots with sed again. There's probably a better way of doing it, but hey, it works!

Comment: Example output:
`text1 valueA valueN valueB
text2 a_b_c_d-e`

Answer (score 1):

Another simple approach with `tac` and `awk`.

```
tac Input_file | awk '$0=="text2 valueX"{print;getline;print}' | tac
```

Output will be as follows.

```
text1 valueA valueN valueB
text2 valueX
text1 valueC valueN valueD
text2 valueX
text1 valueI valueN valueJ
text2 valueX
```

Some `strace` from `tac` (of processing an arbitrary file):

```
lseek(3, 351051776, SEEK_SET)           = 351051776
read(3, "83,10.1579,56.1257,1412067900\n41"..., 8192) = 8192
write(1, "104,210,84,194,10.1313,56.1528,1"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "2092,56.1724,1412068200\n129,20,3"..., 4096) = 4096
lseek(3, 351043584, SEEK_SET)           = 351043584
read(3, "7900\n148,159,77,186,97,10.2090,5"..., 8192) = 8192
write(1, ",140,182,10.1208,56.1784,1412067"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "10.1859,56.1239,1412067900\n53,17"..., 4096) = 4096
lseek(3, 351035392, SEEK_SET)           = 351035392
```

You can see the decreasing position in the `lseek`.

Comment: +1. Learned there is such a thing as `tac`, incidentally opposite of `cat`. Looks neat, but my only worry with this is memory efficiency. I hope that `tac` doesn't load the whole file in memory in order to reverse it.

Comment: @darksky, agree on memory part, added it as an another way of doing this :) could add comments in my solution too about this.

Comment: @darksky No, `tac`doesn't. According to `strace` it reads 8kB blocks from disk, writes 2 4kB blocks (on my disk setup anyway) and lseeks an earlier position in the file.

Comment: @JamesBrown, Thank you James sir for adding information here about tac

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Can I add some `strace`dump to your answer?

Comment: @JamesBrown, you need not to ask sir, always welcome  to add/edit my answer sir, please go ahead;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk 'NR>1&& $0 == "text2 valueX"{print a"\n"$0} {a=$0}' input.txt
```

Note that this scripts prints something only if the current line exactly matches 'text2 valueX'.

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` solution:

```
$ sed -n -e '/text2 valueX/{' -e 'H;x;p;}' -e 'h' file
text1 valueA valueN valueB
text2 valueX
text1 valueC valueN valueD
text2 valueX
text1 valueI valueN valueJ
text2 valueX
```

Change the regex to `/^text2 valueX$/` if you want to match whole line.

It equals to GNU sed's:

```
 sed -n '/text2 valueX/{H;x;p;};h' file
```

POSIX `sed` needs to start a newline or a new `-e` block after `{` open bracket or `}` close bracket.

```
H   Append the contents of pattern space to hold space, separate them by a newline character.
x   Exchange the contents of pattern space and hold space.
p   Print the contents of pattern space.
h   Overwrite the contents of hold space with pattern space.
```

`/text2 valueX/` is the regex, it matches current line(pattern space), if it matched, the command or `{}` block after it will be executed.
Within the block, append the line to hold space, which already have last line in it. Then exchange the hold space with pattern space, then print.
And after the block, push current line into hold space to replace its former content.

Note: with this solution you can't have multiple `text2 valueX` consecutive lines, otherwise it will print extra lines. If such thing happens please comment let me know how you want to dealing with them.

Comment: Thank's for this! Could you please explain the `{' -e 'H;x;p;}' -e 'h'` part?

Comment: @TempoChocolate  Added some explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How do you match part of `valueX`, for example: `val`?

Comment: @TempoChocolate  What do you want for the *part* you matched? Different purpose will have different ways. I suggest you to check [sed's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;/\ntext2 valueX/p;D' file
```

Open a moving window of two lines throughout the length of the file.

If the second line matches `text2 valueX` print both lines.

Delete the first line and repeat.

For the altered question:

```
sed '$!N;/\ntext2.*a\.b\./p;D' file
```

Use the same method but introduce the new pattern as a regexp.

N.B. The new pattern may need metacharacters to be quoted e.g. the period needs to preceeded by a `\`.

```
regexp='a\.b\.'
sed '$!N;/\ntext2.*'"$regexp"'/p;D' file
```